# python create a dataframe the same as the excel table

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Could anyone please help me with how to write the below table in python?

Also in the rows B1 and B4 I would need a python formula that puts in last month last business day.

Everything else are the strings.

[image: Excel Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your problem is, precisely.

But if you want to generate a .csv file (Table) you can follow this tutorial:https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-write-csv-file/

If that is your problem, you can use the code sample below:

```
import csv

last_mont = 'last month'
last_b_day = 'last business day'

rows = []
rows.append(['Previous Month End Date:', f'formula for {last_mont} {last_b_day}?', 'Previous Month End Date:', '20210831'])
rows.append([])
rows.append(['check'])
rows.append([])
rows.append(['', 'report', 'report','Match?'])
rows.append(['position', 'formula 1 goes here', 'formual 2 too', 'formula 1 = formual 2'])
rows.append([])

f = open('output.csv','w')
writer = csv.writer(f)

for row in rows:
    writer.writerow(row)

f.close()
```

It will generate this .csv table: [image]

Answer (score 0):

For reading the CSV file, you should use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
file = ‘path_to_file’
df = pd.read_csv(file)
print(df)
```

[read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) in pandas